# URXVT bash script issue with spawn rules for DWM

Tags: arch-linux, rxvt, dwm

I am running URXVT as my terminal on DWM. I have my config.h set to spawn new terminals in tag 2. I also have wrote a few scripts that I want to spawn in their own tags. For illustration purposes I am only including my `enterssh` script in my config.h but the behavior is the same for all scripts I am attempting to do this with. I am currently having two issues that may or may not be related to each other.

1. When I run the keybind or run it appended to `urxvt -e`, the new terminal window with the program spawns in both tag 2 (based on URXVT class line 30) and in tag 4 (based on enterssh title line 32). I think what is happening is that both rules are being applied to opening up the script but I don't know how to make dwm ignore the first rule for the general terminal.
2. Currently, if I execute the script while in any other tag than the ones in the rule (right now 2 and 4), I just get a blank terminal window. I know the script is partially running because it is creating a log file I have scripted in but I am not sure why it is having trouble displaying output.

Any help would be appreciated because I am stumped.

Here is my config.h:

```
     1  /* See LICENSE file for copyright and license details. */
     2  
     3  /* appearance */
     4  static const unsigned int borderpx  = 1;        /* border pixel of windows */
     5  static const unsigned int snap      = 32;       /* snap pixel */
     6  static const int showbar            = 1;        /* 0 means no bar */
     7  static const int topbar             = 1;        /* 0 means bottom bar */
     8  static const char *fonts[]          = { "inconsolata:size=18" };
     9  static const char dmenufont[]       = "inconsolata:size=18";
    10  static const char col_gray1[]       = "#222222";
    11  static const char col_gray2[]       = "#444444";
    12  static const char col_gray3[]       = "#f47edb";
    13  static const char col_gray4[]       = "#b8ae32";
    14  static const char col_cyan[]        = "#554080";
    15  static const char *colors[][3]      = {
    16      /*               fg         bg         border   */
    17      [SchemeNorm] = { col_gray3, col_gray1, col_gray2 },
    18      [SchemeSel]  = { col_gray4, col_cyan,  col_cyan  },
    19  };
    20  
    21  /* tagging */
    22  static const char *tags[] = { "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "A", "B" };
    23  
    24  static const Rule rules[] = {
    25      /* xprop(1):
    26       *  WM_CLASS(STRING) = instance, class
    27       *  WM_NAME(STRING) = title
    28       */
    29      /* class      instance    title       tags mask     isfloating   monitor */
    30      { "URxvt",    NULL,       NULL,       1 << 1,       0,           -1 },
    31      { "firefox",  NULL,       NULL,       1 << 2,       0,           -1 },
    32      { NULL,       NULL,       "enterssh", 1 << 3,       0,           -1 },
    33  };
    34  
    35  /* layout(s) */
    36  static const float mfact     = 0.55; /* factor of master area size [0.05..0.95] */
    37  static const int nmaster     = 1;    /* number of clients in master area */
    38  static const int resizehints = 1;    /* 1 means respect size hints in tiled resizals */
    39  static const int lockfullscreen = 1; /* 1 will force focus on the fullscreen window */
    40  
    41  static const Layout layouts[] = {
    42      /* symbol     arrange function */
    43      { "",      tile },    /* first entry is default */
    44      { "",      NULL },    /* no layout function means floating behavior */
    45      { "",      monocle },
    46  };
    47  
    48  /* key definitions */
    49  #define MODKEY Mod1Mask
    50  #define TAGKEYS(KEY,TAG) \
    51      { MODKEY,                       KEY,      view,           {.ui = 1 << TAG} }, \
    52      { MODKEY|ControlMask,           KEY,      toggleview,     {.ui = 1 << TAG} }, \
    53      { MODKEY|ShiftMask,             KEY,      tag,            {.ui = 1 << TAG} }, \
    54      { MODKEY|ControlMask|ShiftMask, KEY,      toggletag,      {.ui = 1 << TAG} },
    55  
    56  /* helper for spawning shell commands in the pre dwm-5.0 fashion */
    57  #define SHCMD(cmd) { .v = (const char*[]){ "/bin/sh", "-c", cmd, NULL } }
    58  
    59  /* commands */
    60  static char dmenumon[2] = "0"; /* component of dmenucmd, manipulated in spawn() */
    61  static const char *dmenucmd[] = { "dmenu_run", "-m", dmenumon, "-fn", dmenufont, "-nb", col_gray1, "-nf", col_gray3, "-sb", col_cyan, "-sf", col_gray4, NULL };
    62  static const char *termcmd[]  = { "urxvt", NULL };
    63  static const char *ossh[]  = { "urxvt", "-e", "/home/VCPitcairn/Scripts/enterssh", NULL };
    64  static const char *web[] = { "firefox", NULL};
    65  
    66  static const Key keys[] = {
    67      /* modifier                     key        function        argument */
    68      { MODKEY,                       XK_p,      spawn,          {.v = dmenucmd } },
    69      { MODKEY,                       XK_w,      spawn,          {.v = web} },
    70      { MODKEY,           XK_Return, spawn,          {.v = termcmd } },
    71      { MODKEY,           XK_c,      spawn,          {.v = ossh } },
    72      { MODKEY,                       XK_b,      togglebar,      {0} },
    73      { MODKEY,                       XK_j,      focusstack,     {.i = +1 } },
    74      { MODKEY,                       XK_k,      focusstack,     {.i = -1 } },
    75      { MODKEY,                       XK_i,      incnmaster,     {.i = +1 } },
    76      { MODKEY,                       XK_d,      incnmaster,     {.i = -1 } },
    77      { MODKEY,                       XK_h,      setmfact,       {.f = -0.05} },
    78      { MODKEY,                       XK_l,      setmfact,       {.f = +0.05} },
    79      { MODKEY|ShiftMask,             XK_Return, zoom,           {0} },
    80      { MODKEY,                       XK_Tab,    view,           {0} },
    81      { MODKEY|ShiftMask,             XK_c,      killclient,     {0} },
    82      { MODKEY,                       XK_t,      setlayout,      {.v = &layouts[0]} },
    83      { MODKEY,                       XK_f,      setlayout,      {.v = &layouts[1]} },
    84      { MODKEY,                       XK_m,      setlayout,      {.v = &layouts[2]} },
    85      { MODKEY,                       XK_space,  setlayout,      {0} },
    86      { MODKEY|ShiftMask,             XK_space,  togglefloating, {0} },
    87      { MODKEY,                       XK_0,      view,           {.ui = ~0 } },
    88      { MODKEY|ShiftMask,             XK_0,      tag,            {.ui = ~0 } },
    89      { MODKEY,                       XK_comma,  focusmon,       {.i = -1 } },
    90      { MODKEY,                       XK_period, focusmon,       {.i = +1 } },
    91      { MODKEY|ShiftMask,             XK_comma,  tagmon,         {.i = -1 } },
    92      { MODKEY|ShiftMask,             XK_period, tagmon,         {.i = +1 } },
    93      TAGKEYS(                        XK_1,                      0)
    94      TAGKEYS(                        XK_2,                      1)
    95      TAGKEYS(                        XK_3,                      2)
    96      TAGKEYS(                        XK_4,                      3)
    97      TAGKEYS(                        XK_5,                      4)
    98      TAGKEYS(                        XK_6,                      5)
    99      TAGKEYS(                        XK_7,                      6)
   100      TAGKEYS(                        XK_8,                      7)
   101      TAGKEYS(                        XK_9,                      8)
   102      { MODKEY|ShiftMask,             XK_q,      quit,           {0} },
   103  };
   104  
   105  /* button definitions */
   106  /* click can be ClkTagBar, ClkLtSymbol, ClkStatusText, ClkWinTitle, ClkClientWin, or ClkRootWin */
   107  static const Button buttons[] = {
   108      /* click                event mask      button          function        argument */
   109      { ClkLtSymbol,          0,              Button1,        setlayout,      {0} },
   110      { ClkLtSymbol,          0,              Button3,        setlayout,      {.v = &layouts[2]} },
   111      { ClkWinTitle,          0,              Button2,        zoom,           {0} },
   112      { ClkStatusText,        0,              Button2,        spawn,          {.v = termcmd } },
   113      { ClkClientWin,         MODKEY,         Button1,        movemouse,      {0} },
   114      { ClkClientWin,         MODKEY,         Button2,        togglefloating, {0} },
   115      { ClkClientWin,         MODKEY,         Button3,        resizemouse,    {0} },
   116      { ClkTagBar,            0,              Button1,        view,           {0} },
   117      { ClkTagBar,            0,              Button3,        toggleview,     {0} },
   118      { ClkTagBar,            MODKEY,         Button1,        tag,            {0} },
   119      { ClkTagBar,            MODKEY,         Button3,        toggletag,      {0} },
   120  };
```